# How can I track if someone generates a DDL script in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

IF someone generates a Generate script using SSMS to my database.

How can I trace that something happens with the database?

Is that event recorded by SQL server transaction log or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you need auditing, then you need to configure that. I suggest that you start with the feature named "Server Audit" and see if that suits your needs.

The database engine has no concept of "generate script", the tool just does a bunch of SELECT to do that job. I.e., to track that this happened, you need to have turned on some auditing solution (like above mentioned "Server Audit").

Comment: Thanks Tibor Karaszi for quick help